# Replace first letter of a string

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a dataframe with a column I would like to change the string in it

```
       Num       rand
1  A.AZ.R   0.2500000
2  A.EAZ.B  1.0000000
3  A.AZ.C   0.1000000
4  A.AZE.D  0.0100000
5  A.AZE.E  0.2500000
6  A.RJE.F  0.0156250
7  A.AZE.C  0.0078125
8  A.AVE.G  0.0078125
9  A.AZD.B  0.0312500
```

I would like all `A.` be replaced by `F.` in the `Num` column.

```
       Num       rand
1  F.AZ.R   0.2500000
2  F.EAZ.B  1.0000000
3  F.AZ.C   0.1000000
4  F.AZE.D  0.0100000
5  F.AZE.E  0.2500000
6  F.RJE.F  0.0156250
7  F.AZE.C  0.0078125
8  F.AVE.G  0.0078125
9  F.AZD.B  0.0312500
```

Comment: gsub("R.", "F.", Df) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> df
      Num      rand
1  A.AZ.R 0.2500000
2 A.EAZ.B 1.0000000
3  A.AZ.C 0.1000000
4 A.AZE.D 0.0100000
5 A.AZE.E 0.2500000
6 A.RJE.F 0.0156250
7 A.AZE.C 0.0078125
8 A.AVE.G 0.0078125
9 A.AZD.B 0.0312500

> df[,1] <- gsub("^.", "F", df[,1])
> df
      Num      rand
1  F.AZ.R 0.2500000
2 F.EAZ.B 1.0000000
3  F.AZ.C 0.1000000
4 F.AZE.D 0.0100000
5 F.AZE.E 0.2500000
6 F.RJE.F 0.0156250
7 F.AZE.C 0.0078125
8 F.AVE.G 0.0078125
9 F.AZD.B 0.0312500
```

Answer (score 1):

Chartr is useful for that: 
Assuming your data frame is called df you can do:

```
df$Num <- chartr("A.", "F.", df$Num)
```